# Не работают кнопки на сайте

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте есть слайдер, которые позволяет перемещаться вверх/вниз по странице, но из-за ошибок в js скрипте этого слайдера, не работают все кнопки на сайте, просто не перемещают на другие страницы. Как можно исправить проблему? Проеблмый файл называется jquery-1.10.2.min.js

Comment: Проблемный явно не jquery, а тот, кто обращается к этому jquery. Как исправить — найти настоящую причину с помощью отладчика да исправить её в коде

Answer (score 1):

Проблем в данном файле быть не может, если конечно Вы сами туда залезли.

По этому, проблема **скорее всего** кроется в том, что вы сделали где-то ошибку в JQ коде и\или коде слайдера.

По-этому предоставьте ссылку на сайт\страницу, где замечается данная проблема.
Или добавьте код страницы в вопрос.

---

**Ошибка с блоком "DOWNLOAD WHITEPAPPER"**

По какой-то причине, при нажатии на блок `<div class="home-hover navigation-slide">`, плагин на скролл-контекта пытается определить положение блока до которого нужно доскроллить.

Вот так выглядит блок:

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
  <div class="home-hover navigation-slide">
    <a href="/files/WPCYBERCUPS.pdf">
      <img src="images/WP.png" style="width:20%">
    </a>
  </div>
  <a href="/files/WPCYBERCUPS.pdf">
    <span style="color:white;">DOWNLOAD WHITEPAPPER</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Консоль указывает на ошибку в этой строке:

var offset_top = ( dataslide == 1 ) ? '0px' : $('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top;

Полностью функция выглядит так:

```
function goToByScroll(dataslide) {
  var offset_top = ( dataslide == 1 ) ? '0px' : $('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top;

  htmlbody.stop(false, false).animate({
    scrollTop: offset_top
  }, 1500, 'easeInOutQuart');
}
```

Посмотрев код, понятно, что данная функция вызывается при нажатии на блок с классом `.navigation-slide`, именно он находится в том самом блоке.

**РЕШЕНИЕ**: Удалить класс `navigation-slide` из блока ниже:

```
<div class="home-hover navigation-slide">
```

И так, попробуем разобраться.

---

**Ошибка с навигацией (вверх - вниз)**

Есть открыть код, то мы увидим, что "слайды" - это блоки с идентификатором `data-slide="N"` (Где **N** - ПОРЯДКОВЫЙ НОМЕР слайда).

Сам слайдер работает по принципу определения текущего слайда и при нажатии вниз к идентификатору прибавляет 1.
При нажатие отнимает 1.

У вас, код блоков выглядит так:

```
<div class="slide story" id="slide-1" data-slide="1">
  ...
</div>
<div class="slide story" id="slide-2" data-slide="2">
  ...
</div>
<!--<div class="slide story" id="slide-3" data-slide="3">
  ...
</div>-->
<div class="slide story" id="slide-4" data-slide="4">
  ...
</div>
<div class="slide story" id="slide-5" data-slide="5">
  ...
</div>
<!--<div class="slide story" id="slide-6" data-slide="6">
  ...
</div>-->
```

Ошибка заключается в том, что 3 слайд закомментированы и порядок сбивается (1, 2, 4, 5)
P.s. Почему я указал только 3й слайд? Потому что 6й последний, из-за того, что он закоментирован, последним считается 5ый.

**РЕШЕНИЕ:** изменить код на вот такой:

```
<div class="slide story" id="slide-1" data-slide="1">
  ...
</div>
<div class="slide story" id="slide-2" data-slide="2">
  ...
</div>
<!--<div class="slide story" id="slide-3" data-slide="3">
  ...
</div>-->
<div class="slide story" id="slide-4" data-slide="3">
  ...
</div>
<div class="slide story" id="slide-5" data-slide="4">
  ...
</div>
<!--<div class="slide story" id="slide-6" data-slide="6">
  ...
</div>-->
```

Comment: сайт cybercups.com, кнопка buy tokens не работает, если нажать на кнопку dowload whitepaper, то в консоли летят ошибки

Comment: @Midnight, как я и думал.. Какое действие дожно происходить после нажатии кнопки "download whitepaper"?

Comment: Должен произойти переход на страницу http://cybercups.com/files/WPCYBERCUPS.pdf

Comment: @Midnight, изменил ответ, добавив туда решение двух ваших проблем.

Comment: Касаемо ссылки, попробовал оставить вот так, <div class="col-12 col-sm-4"><div class="" ><a href="/files/WPCYBERCUPS.pdf"><img src="images/WP.png" style="width:20%"></a></div><a href="/files/WPCYBERCUPS.pdf"><span style="color:white;">DOWNLOAD WHITEPAPPER</span></a></div>, но все равно не переходит

Comment: @Midnight, как мне кажется, что что-то блокируется ссылку.. Но это не точно

Comment: Кнопка buy tokens также не работает

Comment: Может костыли есть какие-то?